# Zeros of derivative of composition of polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

Let $f(x),g(x)$ be polynomials such that their derivatives $f'(x),g'(x)$ have  $n$ and  $m$  real roots. What is the possible minimal/maximal numbers of real roots for the polynomial $(f(g(x))'$?

My idea was as follows. Since $(f(g(x))'=f'(g(x)) g'(x)$ then  minimal numbers of real roots is $m$ and  the maximal number of the roots is $m+n.$  An I right?

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: The minimum is right, the maximum isn't.

Comment: well, $f'(g(x))$ is a polynomial of degree at last $n m$. So it can  have $n m$ roots?

Comment: The idea is right, but the degrees are not quite right.

Comment: oh,  the dergee is $n(m+1).$